# YouCompleteMe unavailable: No module named builtins

Tags: python, vim, youcompleteme

I have installed YCM and am getting the following message when opening a file in vim

```
YouCompleteMe unavailable: No module named builtins
```

I have tried following the trouble shooting tips found [here](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/2724) including running the following command;

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

My output from running `:py import pprint; pprint.pprint(sys.path)` is the following;

```
[u'/Users/my_name/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/python',
u'/Users/my_name/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/requests-futures',
 u'/Users/my_name/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd',
 u'/Users/my_name/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/requests_deps/idna',
 u'/Users/my_name/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/requests_deps/chardet',
 u'/Users/my_name/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/requests_deps/urllib3/src',
 u'/Users/my_name/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/requests_deps/certifi',
 u'/Users/my_name/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/requests_deps/requests',
 u'/Users/my_name/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/pythonfutures',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.20.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 u'/Users/my_name/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/python-future/src',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/my_name/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '_vim_path_']
```

Edit: I am trying to get autocomplete for python specifically, running MacOS Mojave, and installed using the installation instructions found [here](https://gist.github.com/ChengLong/6208775)

Comment: The error indicates that that code requires Python 3, and won't work on Python 2.

Comment: Good catch, I do have python 3, is there a reason it is not running on it?

Comment: No idea. I do note that the bug report you found [predates this comment removing `python-future` imports](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/commit/f3ccafe3aedee0dc2ec320e3121869785e730bb8). Personally, I can certainly recommend not using python-future to bridge Python 2 and 3, but that commit appears to have left you with no Python 2 support.

Comment: That said, I don't know anything about YCM, and [the continuous testing infra](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/blob/master/.travis.yml) tests against both Python 2 and Python 3, so *something* is probably still installing the alias at some point, and that doesn't happen in your case.